# Issues with Java3D in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error, java-3d, java-13

Eclipse is giving a NoClassDefFoundError for all the 3D classes when I attempt to run my Java3d program, even though the ide doesn't show any errors when I import and use classes from java3d. I moved the lib jars and bin dll from Java3d into the jdk classpath and bin respectivally and have added the 3djars into the build path of my eclipse project. What have I missed/done wrong?

Comment: Hello, you don't provide enough information. Please strictly follow the instruction of the Java3D user's guide I wrote: https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#eclipse Contact the JogAmp community on our official forum rather than here. StackOverflow isn't the panacea. By the way, what you did is a bad practice and can break other programs, please clean up the mess, don't put native libraries and JARs into the JDK/JRE.

Comment: 1)right click on project->properties->libraries add all j3d jar files.     2)copy all DLL files into your project folder in file explorer